# jquery :not not working

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

Here is my HTML

```
<div class="records" id="1">
        <div class="controls">
            <a class="special">
                <img class="1" src="special1.png" class="shown" />
                <img class="1" src="special0.png" class="hidden" />
            </a>
        </div>
</div>

<div class="records" id="2">
        <div class="controls">
            <a class="special">
                <img class="1" src="special1.png" class="hidden" />
                <img class="0" src="special0.png" class="shown"/>
            </a>
        </div>
</div>
```

It is HTML output of what is retrieved from db. But at one time, only one of the images are shown in one record either `special1.png` or `special0.png`, but when user clicks at any `a.special` I want the `special1.png` of that record to be visible and all the images in other `a.special` have to only display `special0.png`. For this I tried to do this using this

```
$(".controls a").click(function() {
    var action = $(this).attr('class');
    var id = $(this).parent(".controls").parent(".records").attr('id');

    //Now send post request and database things
    //function(data) { //After this stage
       $(this).children("img.1").show(); //show the active image
       $(this).children("img.0").hide(); //hide the inactive image

    //However this below I used :not to skip current element but it doesn't, it hides all inactive image and shows all active images

       $("div:not(#"+id+") a.special img.1").hide(); //hide all the active image except this one 
       $("div:not(#"+id+") a.special img.0").show(); //show all the in-active image except this one 

    // } //
});
```

Comment: @mrNepal one mistake in your code , don't use numbers as div ids, its not allowed and not a good practice.

Comment: @gov, what would you suggest to hold the `id` of a records, for use of ajax purpose. But this has to assigned when view is being fetched using database

Comment: @mrNepal use some other values , if they are dynamic give some name and then no ,  numbers for div ids and classes are not allowed and it can give wierd results , it doesn't show any where.

Comment: @gov: "its not allowed and not a good practice". somehow, I disagree. Numbers are valid as long as they are correctly used.

Comment: @gov, then how to extract the id only part from the name

Comment: @mrNepal, you could create a pattern for div ids like: "divRecords1", "divRecords2" and etc. and then when you get the id of div, you can easily replace `divRecords` with an empty string so you'll get the actual div id.

Comment: My actual question however is, why is the `:not` I used not working, Could you guys please tell me something about this?

Comment: @conqentor , where did you read that numbers are allowed as div ids and class, to my knowledge its not correct

Comment: @gov: It's in the language specifications by w3c. For a simple reference, here's http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_standard_id.asp  .Which states Id's  - a> Must begin with a letter A-Z or a-z
b> Can be followed by: letters (A-Za-z), digits (0-9), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".")

Answer (score 2):

First, I think `:not()` is failing because you are using numbers as IDs, which is not allowed in HTML4.  All `id` attributes must start with an alphabetic character.  You could prefix your ids with `r`, for instance:

```
<div class="records" id="r1">
```

Second, you can do this much more efficiently using the [`.not`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) method:

```
$(".controls a").click(function() {
    var action = this.class;
    var record = $(this).closest(".records")[0]; // get the DOM element of the ancestor .records

    //Now send post request and database things
    //function(data) { //After this stage
       $(this).children("img.r1").show(); //show the active image
       $(this).children("img.r0").hide(); //hide the inactive image

       $("div").not(record).find("a.special img.r1").hide(); //hide all the active image except this one 
       $("div").not(record).find("a.special img.0").show(); //show all the in-active image except this one 

    // } //
});
```

Note the use of

- `this.class` to replace `$(this).attr('class')`
- [`.closest('.records')`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to find the closest ancestor element with the class `records`
- `[0]` to get the DOM element from the jQuery selection
- [`.not(record)`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) to remove the `record` element from the set
- [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to find all descendent elements matching a particular selector

Comment: +1 for pointing out the use of .closest(). Hadn't come across it yet.

Answer (score 0):

It would be worth trying the [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/) method. It makes your selector cleaner and can also take function as as argument which lends more capability.

Also,as I've already mentioned - HTML4 Id's 
a> must begin with a letter A-Z or a-z
b> Can be followed by: letters (A-Za-z), digits (0-9), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".")

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its the issue of `:not`.

You see, in your first `div`, both the images have `class="1"`. that might be the issue. try setting `class="0"` to one image of them.

Comment: I agree, :not vs .not() is "not" the issue here. Just a recommendation based on my past experince.